# Unknown Method - ActiveField::radioButtonList() in Yii2

Tags: yii2, radiobuttonlist

I want to display `RadioButton List` in form.

I tried using below code:

```
<?php
$list = [0 => 'Morning', 1 => 'Noon', 2 => 'Evening'];

/* Display a stacked checkbox list */
echo $form->field($model, 'is_active')->radioButtonList($list);
?>
```

But I got error below:

```
Unknown Method – yii\base\UnknownMethodException
Calling unknown method: yii\widgets\ActiveField::radioButtonList()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
 $list = [0 => 'Morning', 1 => 'Noon', 2 => 'Evening'];
 echo $form->field($model, 'is_active')->radioList($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps:

```
<?= $form->field($ShipmentTypeForm, 'shipmenttype')
         ->radioList(['radio1'=>'radio1','radio2'=>'radio2'],['class'=>'your_class','id'=>'your_id']); ?>
```